# Call one rule from another in clips

Tags: rules, rule-engine, clips

I wanted to know if there is any possibility of firing a rule from the RHS of another rule.
for example,

```
rule 1:
(defrule printHello
=>
(printout t " Hello World" crlf ))

rule 2:
(defrule printName
=> 
/* tigger rule 1 */)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expert systems are knowledge representation engines. They use knowledge (static and dynamic) to represent their internal state. In CLIPS, dynamic knowledge is represented with facts.

You can use a custom dedicated fact for that.

```
(defrule printHello
  (print hello)
=>
  (printout t " Hello World" crlf))

(defrule printName
=>
  (assert (print hello)))
```

Comment: Is there a way to call the other rule without using to assert values?